# Why AntiXss library is not supported for Web Api the same way as MVC does?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, xss

According to Microsoft starting from .NET 4.0 the [AntiXSS](http://wpl.codeplex.com) is included in the framework and enabled by default.
this is true for MVC but when it comes to Web Api there is no proper solution.

for example I have this very basic API flow:

```
public class MessageViewModel
{
    public int TargetID { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

and the Api Controller:

```
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public MessageResponse SendMessage(MessageViewModel model)
    {
        MessageResponse response = null;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            response = _logic.SendMessage(model);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

this Content property of the MessageViewModel object may contains malicious scripts/code that later on will be sent to another users.

is there a way to enable the AntiXSS on Web Api the same way it works for MVC? and if not, what proper solution exist to protect the entire application from XSS without applying attributes on each specific view model?